# Which piece of code avoids race conditions when loading images to a table view?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, image

I'm trying to asynchronously display images in a tableview without overriding old images in cells that are reused. I was told to try the (1)st method down below, and it worked when I ran it on a device, but went I submitted my code for code review, I was then told by another engineer that method (1) still results in race conditions because the validation is done off the main thread. In what case would the cell change AGAIN after the network request has already validated that the cell hasn't been reused yet that the bottom (1) would cover and top (2) wouldn't?

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: EmployeeTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? EmployeeTableViewCell else {
            fatalError()
        }
        let employee = viewModel.employees[indexPath.row]
        cell.uuid = employee.uuid

        AsyncNetworking.fetchImageFor(employee: employee) { result in
            guard cell.uuid == employee.uuid else { return } // 1. here
            switch result {
            case let .success(data):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    guard cell.uuid == employee.uuid else { return } // 2. or here
                    cell.setImage(image: UIImage(data: data))
                }
            case .failure:
                ...
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Then where do you call them?

Comment: @LeoDabus I personally avoid the pattern but it's worth noting that Apple's own sample code from their documentation about async image loading in table and collection views does all the async work inside `cellForRow`/`cellProvider`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views/asynchronously_loading_images_into_table_and_collection_views

Comment: I would agree, it is acceptable and the code seems to avoid race conditions. Personally I would move the code into another class that handled caching.  I would probably use SDWebImage but 3rd party code may not be an option for the op.

Comment: @Huy-AnhHoang you can remove the initial guard and just force downcast the cell.  Either way you get a crash but with the force downcast you get a more meaningful exception that will help you diagnose the problem

Comment: Look at the sample code in my previous comment. The idea is to give the async method the item behind the cell and have it return that item when it returns the downloaded image. Then you check whether this item is already rendered in the table and if it has an image (or the same image you just downloaded). Using a diffable datasource for your table is really the way to go here (if you don't need to support iOS prior to 13). You're very close to what you need and you will find your answer in the sample code in that link.